# Jsoup and cookie - I can't logg to everything subsite

Tags: cookies, jsoup

I've issue about keeping cookie in Jsoup. I logged on main site through JSON, here is everything fine. I've problem when I want go to next subsite, I put the same cookie and this isn't work. In my console I can see that I have html site before logg. Any ideas what should I change?

```java
public class MyBenefit {
    final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15";
    final static String LOGIN_FORM_URL = "https://system.mybenefit.pl/mybenefit/login.html";
    final static String LOGIN_ACTION_URL = "https://system.mybenefit.pl/mybenefit/login/by_email";
    final static String URL = "https://system.mybenefit.pl/mybenefit/benefit-login-dispatcher.html";
    final static String URLQUERY = "https://system.mybenefit.pl/mybenefit/global-search.html?query=";
    final static String USERNAME = "xxx";
    final static String PASSWORD = "xxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_FORM_URL)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .execute();

            //here I create json, because json is required to login
            JsonBuilderFactory jsonBuilderFactory = Json.createBuilderFactory(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonBuilderFactory.createObjectBuilder()
                    .add("password", PASSWORD)
                    .add("captcha", "")
                    .add("lang", "pl")
                    .add("email", USERNAME).build();


            HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>(loginForm.cookies());

            Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_ACTION_URL)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .requestBody(jsonObject.toString())
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .execute();

            //here I get cookie after logg
            String sessionID = homePage.cookie("BENEFIT_SESSIONID");

            //this connection is working
            Connection.Response afterLogg = Jsoup.connect(URL)
                    .cookie("BENEFIT_SESSIONID", sessionID)
                    .execute();

            Document document = afterLogg.parse();

            //this connection is NOT workingg good, I am not logged on website
            Connection.Response test = Jsoup.connect(URLQUERY)
                    .cookie("BENEFIT_SESSIONID", sessionID)
                    .execute();

            System.out.println(test.parse());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I checked on developers tools in Firefox, and page URL and page URLQUERY has the same cookie. I send some pictures about this. [cookie after logg on URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39CI3.png) [cookie on URLQUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3sdV.png)

Comment: Check that your Jsoup requests are equivalent to the browser requests. For example, in the not working request you are not setting "userAgent" or any other header, you are not passing a "query" parameter neither.

Comment: I've checked request header form browser. https://imgbox.com/upload/edit/500214143/hpCKKZIXDlbKzWi6 I added: referrer, method connection and user agent and still not working. "Query" parameter is not necessary right there. You can see that on image.